# C++ API - return a pointer of an object with extern "C"

Tags: c#, c++, api, pointers

I'm programming an API for a C++ simulation framework. 
And I want to use this API for example in C#.
But I need a pointer to an object in that framework in C# so I can do something with that object.

So I tried this:

```
extern "C" ObjectClass GetObject() {
    return someOtherObject->getObject(); <-- returns an object of ObjectClass
}
```

This will not build at all.
Maybe this is really the wrong way but don't know how to do this right way.

Comment: Unless we know the prototype of that function being called, we can't help you.

Comment: You mean the getObject function?

Comment: You can't use objects in C, but you could pass a `void *` and then convert it back to the relevant class with a `reinterpret_cast` in the C++ code.

Comment: Correct. Unless the object is a C style `struct`, you can't return it as you would be returning a C++ object through a C function.